# Mysql count return Zero if no record found

Tags: mysql, zero

I have a two tables.

```
cities - id_city, city_name
properties - id_property, id_city, property_name
```

I want to display `cities.city_name` and next to it `[properties.count(id_city)]`

How do I make a query that still returns zero if no records are found instead of `NULL`, so that I get results like this:

```
London [123]
New York [0]
Berlin [11]
```

where "New York" is [0], not `NULL` and not 1?

Comment: Your question isn't clear....

Comment: I did my best to clean it up a bit so it was clearer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use an outer join:

```
select cities.city_name, count(properties.id_city)
  from cities left join properties on cities.id_city = properties.id_city
  group by 1
```

Comment: select cities.city_name, count(*)
  from cities left join properties on cities.id_city = properties.id_city
  group by 1

Comment: it's wrong!
it gives back results with "1" even if there is no matches

Comment: try count(properties.id_property) instead of count(*)

Comment: I've changed the query - take a look. Instead of count(*) you should use count(column from left joined table)

Answer (score 23):

I think the following will do it for you, though I haven't tested it. The trick is to get the property counts in one table, and then to left join that table to the cities table, converting NULLs to 0s using the [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function.

```
SELECT city_name, IFNULL(property_count, 0)
FROM cities
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT id_city, count(*) as property_count
    FROM properties
    GROUP BY id_city) city_properties
   USING (id_city);
```

Answer (score 3):

The query:

```
SELECT cities.*, COUNT(properties.id_city) as num
FROM cities
LEFT JOIN properties on cities.id_city=properties.id_city
GROUP BY cities.id_city
```

should return a 0 count where you want it, although I'm not 100% certain it works that way in MySQL.

Comment: What does this query do?

Answer (score -4):

Simple. Use "(Count(*) + 0)". Any null plus 0 will return a number.

Comment: But it does not return a 0 if there is no entry created in list.

Comment: it does not return anything