# Laravel get count of results based on groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

The following is the structure of my database

```
id  name  country  province   status  updated_at    
1   A     US       TX         2       [timestamp]
2   B     UK       LON        1       [timestamp]
3   C     US       TX         2       [timestamp]
4   D     US       WA         2       [timestamp]
5   E     US       WA         3       [timestamp]
6   F     US       WA         2       [timestamp]
7   G     US       TX         1       [timestamp]
```

Information from the form (search criteria)

- country (US) in this example
- Start date, End date

I need to get the following count and information.

- Group by province {

  - $ca = count(status '1')
  - $cb = count(status '2')
  - $cc = count(status '3') }

Expected result:: 'US' search criteria:-

```
Province TX
    Status '1': 1
    Status '2': 2
    Status '3': 0

Province WA
    Status '1': 0
    Status '2': 2
    Status '3': 1
```

The following is what i trying to do but failed

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->where('country', $b)
->select('province', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
->groupBy('province')
->whereBetween('updated_at', [
        \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($d, $e)->startOfMonth(),
        \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($f, $g)->endOfMonth()
    ])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: My raw MySQL is a little rusty, apologies for any mistakes.*

**Problem 1: You're grouping by the wrong column(s).**

If you want to know the totals of each individual status for each individual province for each individual country, you need to specify all of those items in your `GROUP BY` clause. As it is, your `COUNT` will determine the number of unique provinces.

```
GROUP BY country, province, status
```

**Problem 2: Statuses with no entries will not show up.**

Unless you are joining to an outside table for each status, you will not get any counts for non-existent statuses. Given your provided data, the raw results would look more like this:

```
Country  Province  Status  Total
US       TX        1       1
US       TX        2       2
US       WA        2       2
US       WA        3       1
```

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528688/mysql-count-return-zero-if-no-record-found) of how to accomplish zero counts for non-existent entries. Using this will totally depend on your data and DB structure.

**Potential caveats: `ORDER BY`**

Ordering by the `created_at` column seems pointless. If you'd like your expected results, you'll want to order specifically by that information:

```
ORDER BY country, province, status
```

**Solution**

I won't include the join to retrieve any zero-result statuses. But here's an untested example of how to translate to Query Builder:

```
$results = DB::table('users')
    ->select(['country', 'province', 'status', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS total')])
    ->where('country', '=', $b)
    ->whereBetween('updated_at', [
        \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($d, $e)->startOfMonth(),
        \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($f, $g)->endOfMonth()
    ])
    ->groupBy('country', 'province', 'status')
    ->orderBy('country') // defaults to ASC
    ->orderBy('province')
    ->orderBy('status')
    ->get();
```

**Alternative Solution**

An alternative to a semi-complicated query might be to simply query the set of information you need (entries belonging to `$b` country, and in between the provided `updated_at` times), and then process it yourself in PHP.

Laravel's [Collection](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html) class has handy methods built-in for going over data. These, or even a raw `foreach()` could get you the information you need. Whatever works best for your situation.