# Get last 7 days count even when there are no records

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-4, aggregate-functions

How can I make a SQL query that returns me something like

```
---------------------   
|DATE       | Count |   
---------------------   
|2015/01/07 |  7    |   
|2015/01/06 |  0    |   
|2015/01/05 |  8    |   
|2015/01/04 |  5    |   
|2015/01/03 |  0    |   
|2015/01/02 |  4    |   
|2015/01/01 |  2    |         
---------------------
```

When there are no records for the 6th and 3rd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a calendar table containing all the dates you need. You can then left join it to your data to get what you are after

Comment: I finally end up creating a dates table and left joining with it

Answer (score 4):

You need a table of all the sequence numbers from 0 to 6. This is easy to generate in a simple query, as follows.

```
           SELECT 0 AS seq 
             UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 
             UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4
             UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL SELECT 6
```

Next, let's use this to construct a virtual table of seven dates. For this example, we pick today and the six preceding days.

```
        SELECT DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL seq.seq DAY theday   
          FROM (
                   SELECT 0 AS seq 
                     UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 
                     UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4
                     UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL SELECT 6
                ) seq
```

Then you do your summary query. You didn't say exactly how it goes so I will guess.  This one gives you the records from six days ago until today. Today is still in progress.

```
        SELECT DATE(i.item_time) theday
               COUNT(*) `count`
          FROM items i
          WHERE i.item_time >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAYS
         GROUP BY DATE(i.item_time)
```

Finally, starting with the list of days, let's LEFT JOIN that summary to it.

```
 SELECT thedays.theday, IFNULL(summary.`count`,0) `count`
   FROM (
        SELECT DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL seq.seq DAY theday   
          FROM (
                   SELECT 0 AS seq 
                     UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 
                     UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4
                     UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL SELECT 6
                ) seq 
          ) thedays
   LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DATE(i.item_time) theday
               COUNT(*) `count`
          FROM items i
          WHERE i.item_time >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAYS
         GROUP BY DATE(i.item_time)
       ) summary USING (theday)
   ORDER BY thedays.theday
```

It looks complex, but it is simply the combination of three basic queries. Think of it as a sandwich, with bread and cheese and tomato stuck together with an `ORDER BY` toothpick.

Here's a more thorough writeup. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

MariaDB version 10 has built-in virtual tables of cardinal number sequences like seq_0_to_6. This is convenient.

Comment: That's a great answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but what if I want it dynamic, I mean, I want the last 7 days from today?

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol The answer I gave offers you today and the preceding six days.  Notice the use of `NOW()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a dummy dates table and left join your current table against it.

```
SELECT dummy.date, SUM(IFNULL(yourtable.record,0)) recordcount
FROM dummy
LEFT JOIN yourtable on dummy.date=yourtable.date
GROUP BT dummy.date
```

please note that I'm replacing nulls with a zero.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to use left join, converting NULLs to 0s using the IFNULL function. Try to match your table and use left join.

Comment: Try to see this question its all most same as in your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528688/mysql-count-return-zero-if-no-record-found.